# Badge icons -- is this a bug?

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, notification-bar, achievements-dialog

When looking at the recent achievements drop downs, the icon for badges appears with the graphic for whatever site you're currently on, rather than the graphic for the site you've earned the badge for.

For instance, in this screenshot, I'm on the Science Fi & Fantasy site, and the badge in the drop-down is from Code Review.

[image]

On Code Review, this would be a simply bronze circle, but on SF&F it's this emblem.

Is this a bug, or is this working as intended?